# create an android apk that only update a resource image file

Tags: android

Is it possible to create an .apk file that only update an image in the existing app? my app is an in-house app for corporation, not in the play store, mainly contain of images (in the resource folder), and i just want to create a patch (an apk that is significant smaller size) that only update one of the images in the existing version.

Comment: I think it should get trough. Just try to put it in the store and see what happens. Don't forget to increase the version code, just as you would with a normal update. You should consider that your users might expect some visible changes if they are prompted to update, and it looks pretty silly in the update field if you just replaced one image. Maybe add a point like "various bugfixes", so they don't know they have to update just for one image.

Comment: As long as you maintain the package name your app will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app change image in the res folder of another app it may be possible(not sure it can be impossible at all) for rooted devices.Because all app folders created by the android system for the installed application are protected and can not be accessible for another processes.
But if the image was created on SD-card or on the shared device memory it is not a problem.

Comment: sry, my fault :( it is the same app. I want to create a new version just to update an image. If the app itself is 100mb, and i just want to update one image from it, its not efficient to ask 10 tablets to download the whole thing again.